# Nullreference error in reportdocument.setdatasource crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a problem in crystal reports the `rep_doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);` has an error i don't know whats wrong with the code please help thanks in advance.
The datable has values but its still showing null reference exception at `CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep_doc;` Please help thanks in advance.
the first part is aspx.cs code and second is aspx code

```
public void noOfEvents()
{
     dtEvents = objAdmin.GetNoOfEvents();
     if (dtEvents != null)
     {
        //Report Code
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtEvents);
        ReportDocument rep_doc = new ReportDocument();
        rep_doc.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/Events.rpt"));
        rep_doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep_doc;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
      }
}


<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

errors are as follows:

```
Line 42: rep_doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
Line 43:      
Line 44:CrystalReport1.ReportSource = rep_doc;
Line 45:CrystalReport1.DataBind();
Line 46:CrystalReport1.RefreshReport();



[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Assistvoter.Admin.Report.noOfEvents() in D:\ActiveProjects\Assist Voter\Assistvoter    \Admin\Report.aspx.cs:44
   Assistvoter.Admin.SuperAdmin.Button15_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in     D:\ActiveProjects\Assist Voter\Assistvoter\Admin\SuperAdmin.aspx.cs:95
```

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +141
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +149
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +39
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String     eventArgument) +37
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +87
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean     includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4225

Comment: @Damith it is a simple thing i dono whats the error...Please help

Comment: in error you have `CrystalReport1` but in the code you have `CrystalReportViewer1`.  what is correct?

Comment: try by giving full path like `rep_doc.Load("D:\ActiveProjects\Assist Voter\Assistvoter\Reports\Events.rpt");`

Comment: CrystalReport1 is correct i changed now thats it...

Comment: Still the same result...:(

Comment: Nullreference: Object reference not set to instance of an object . @Damith

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `CrystalReportViewer1` is null. Put a code to check for null value to avoid using object's properties and methods if it is null.

Comment: Coz dataset and datable values are not null

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with this code `reportDocument.SetDataSource(dataset);`, I got the exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. After hours trying everything I solved the issue by removing this

`<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion" 
           publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

from the App.config and it worked. I hope this can help.